# Cannot install pytorch3d using conda or pip on windows 11

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, conda, pytorch3d

I'm trying to install pytorch3d, but neither conda or pip can find the pytorch3d package.

I followed the pytorch instructions: https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d/blob/main/INSTALL.md

The runtime dependencies can be installed by running:

```
conda create -n pytorch3d python=3.9
conda activate pytorch3d
conda install pytorch=1.13.0 torchvision pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
conda install -c fvcore -c iopath -c conda-forge fvcore iopath
```

For the CUB build time dependency, which you only need if you have CUDA older than 11.7 (I have CUDA 12), if you are using conda, you can continue with

```
conda install -c bottler nvidiacub
```

Anaconda Cloud

```
conda install pytorch3d -c pytorch3d
```

I get the error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch3d
```

When I run:

```
pip install pytorch3d
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch3d (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch3d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed something in the docs that you followed. Note that under **Installing prebuilt binaries for PyTorch3D** there is **Install with CUDA support from Anaconda Cloud, on Linux only**, so installing using conda is only supported on linux. You can also see this if you search on anaconda.org and check the page https://anaconda.org/pytorch3d/pytorch3d:

[image]

Note how it only has a linux-x64 tag

For `pip`, we can check the available files on PyPi [here](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch3d/#files):

[image]

Note that there are only macOS files.

To summarize: Neither of your installation methods are supported on windows. You will need to install from source.

The main command to do so is

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d.git@stable"
```